# how to make a springboot webservice for as400 db2 with gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jdbc, db2-400, jt400

I am trying to make a springboot webservice for as400 db2 with gradle. 
I have a webservice for sql with grdle. What changes should I make to connect it to DB2400??

Comment: Please post your database connection code/configuration. 

Usually you have a datasource that specifies a connection string and a jdbc driver class name, so you just change that to point to your DB2 instance.

Comment: That is the main problem I am not able to find out which jar files or drivers I should use for making connection with the database. I have the username and password and the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the JDBC driver here:

https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/downloads.html

Gradle dependency for the driver:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jt400/jt400
compile group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400', version: '9.4'
```

The FAQ which includes the driver class name etc can be found here:

https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/jdbc.html

Comment: I tried this but I am not able to conect this error is coming:    `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I have to add it using db2 jcc4 instead of toolbox.                                        `// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2.jcc/db2jcc4
compile group: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc', name: 'db2jcc4', version: '10.1'`           
                                             And do I have to add more dependencies for it to work??

Comment: **my application-dev-properties**:  `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:db2: <br/>
spring.datasource.username = *
spring.datasource.password = *
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

logging.config = classpath:log4j.properties
#following is needed if you are deploying to tomcat
#logging.file = ${catalina.home}/logs/daily.log
logging.file = ./logs/daily.log
logging.level.* = info

common.page.rownumber=100`

Answer (score 0):

Check my case, there my code works and there are all the configurations. The code has a problem with the saves and it is because of the transactions, which I have tried to fix. But check if your db2 doesn't have this transaction problem: [error when doing an insert or an update with springboot and a database bd2 as400 ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624315/error-when-doing-an-insert-or-an-update-with-springboot-and-a-database-bd2-as400)